# MassTransit - schedule message with custom headers

Tags: masstransit

I schedule messages using `IMessageScheduler` interface. I need to set some custom headers for scheduled messages but I cannot find a way to do that.
For standard (not-scheduled) send/publish I do this using `Action<SendContext<T>>`/`Action<PublishContext<T>>` callbacks but I cannot see any similar arguments in `IMessageScheduler` interface. Is there any possibility to set headers for scheduled messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't built-in extension methods, but you can create a pipe and pass it when scheduling the message:

```cs
ScheduleSend(message, Pipe.ExecuteAsync<SendContext<T>>(context => context.Headers.Set(...)
```